C# & EF Core : multiple relationships between two tables
There is a first model containing a user
public class User_Profiles
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<order>? orders { get; set; }
}

There is a second model containing an order class:
public class order
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int Сreated_UserID { get; set; }
    public User_Profiles Сreated_User { get; set; }
    public int ExecudedUserID { get; set; }
    public User_Profiles ExecudedUser { get; set; }
}

Next I wrote in the context class what is connected
modelBuilder.Entity<order>()
     .HasOne(ps => ps.Сreated_User)
     .WithMany()
     .HasForeignKey(ps => ps.Сreated_UserID)
     .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

modelBuilder.Entity<order>()
     .HasOne(ps => ps.ExecudedUser)
     .WithMany()
     .HasForeignKey(ps => ps.ExecudedUserID)
     .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

The connections are established, everything works, but if you look at the database table, a user_profileid column is created.
How to establish such connections correctly and how to avoid creating an unnecessary column?

I would suggest you NOT name with underscores like User_Profiles make that UserProfiles or perhaps UserProfiles  would be a list/collection of UserProfile and what you have as User_Profiles is really UserOrders?  Good names make your code much easier to maintain and understand

Are you're trying to make one-to-oneand one-to-many relationships between the User_Profiles and Document_Dependency_Model(orders) tables or something else ?
And is that table Document_Dependency_Model i actually orderor what ?

I gave a simplified example that accidentally included the name Document_Dependency_Model, I corrected it almost immediately.
The essence of my initial task is to build a model and connections that meet the following condition:
We have an order or a document (it doesn’t really matter) which has a number of users of the system performing different functions, it turns out that in the properties of the order model there should be order creators, order executors and other different persons who are associated with the user model one to many

Solution:
Changed the User_Profiles model to the state:
public class UserProfile
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Order>? CreatedLink { get; set; }
    public List<Order>? ExecutedLink {get; set;}
}

Next I changed the model order:
public class Order
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int СreatedUserID { get; set; }
    public UserProfile СreatedUser { get; set; }
    public int ExecudedUserID { get; set; }
    public UserProfile ExecudedUser { get; set; }
}

Made changes to the context class
modelBuilder.Entity<order>()
     .HasOne(ps => ps.СreatedUser)
     .WithMany(ps=>psCreatedLink)
     .HasForeignKey(ps => ps.СreatedUserID)
     .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

modelBuilder.Entity<order>()
     .HasOne(ps => ps.ExecudedUser)
     .WithMany(ps=>ps.ExecutedLink)
     .HasForeignKey(ps => ps.ExecudedUserID)
     .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

And as a result, the field disappeared, disappeared, the connection works and it’s probably more correct this way when the navigation properties are separated
